# Mask/Change certain response codes with Apache

Tags: apache, http, proxy, response

I have an apache http server (A) with mod_proxy enabled sending all requests to a second machine (B).

In a normal situation a request X will go to server A and then be sent to server B. Server B will return a response to server A which in turn will send it to the user.

I would like to mask some response codes from the user, so for example, if Server B returns 403, I want Server A to return a 500 to the user.

I have been doing some research in matter but I am not able to find a concrete answer. My first idea was to try ErrorDocument but nothing happened when I tried (Probably due to proxy). My next idea was to use mod_rewrite however it seems the IF statement in Apache's conf file does not give me the option to look at the return code.

Is this even possible with Apache, maybe with a mod, or would I have to rely on a external application for that? I'd prefer to have total control of the returned answer so that not only the response status can be changed but the whole html itself, if possible.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

mod-proxy has a [ProxyErrorOverride](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyerroroverride) directive that works with [mod_include](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_include.html) to allow you to serve content of your choosing in response to proxy origin (behind) HTTP error codes (400-599).

It is not clear to me if it can change the actual response code returned to the client, but if you try it out, please let us know in the replies!

Comment: Oops. I didn't check the date of the question. Did you find a solution? I need to do something similar but changing a "201 Created" to a "200 OK" for a crappy client that can't accept anything else as success. I'm hunting through similar questions but may have to post a new one.